# operators precedence in C

Tags: c, math

have a trouble understanding this expression:

```
(x + y - 1) / y * y
```

The operators precedence is as follows (as per my understanding and K&R2, 2.12 table 2.1):

1) evaluate what is in the parens: firstly (x+y), then (x+y) -1

2) '*' operator has higher priority then '/' so it's supposed to go first, bit it appears  that (y * y)  is evaluated and then the result of (x+y-1) is divided by the product (y*y). I don't quite get it.

3) I ever heard that normally rounding up iw written in this form:

```
(x + y - 1) / y * y
```

Is that correct? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: +1 good explanation of your line of reasoning and asking where it went wrong. This is what a *good* newbie question should look like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned earlier the "*" and "/" have the same precedence so they are evaluated left to right. Totally disambiguating the expression gives:

```
( ( ( (x + y) - 1) / y) * y)
```

Answer (score 6):

Unary operator `*` has higher precedence than `/`, but that is for pointer dereferencing.

Multiplication `*` and division `/` have the same left-to-right precedence.

Comment: Ah, good catch on the indirection (dereferencing) operator.  Showing that there is a differing uses for the same symbols (and thus the confusion).

Answer (score 5):

no, `*` and `/` have same precedence. (it is called "[precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)", not "priority")

```
(x + y - 1) / y * y
```

would be

```
( ( (x+y) - 1 ) / y ) * y
```

The operation tree would be:

```
           *
          / \
         /   y
        ÷
       / \
      /   y
     -
    / \
   /   1
  +
 / \
x   y
```

Answer (score 2):

1) right

2) No, "/" and "*" is the same priority. So it will be performed from left to right.

3) I don't understand what your "round up" mean. But for example:

With y = 2, x = 2

(x + y -1) / y * y = (2 + 2 - 1) / 2 * 2 = (3 / 2) * 2 = **1 * 2** = 2

3 / 2 = 1 because this is the division of integer.

Answer (score 1):

> '*' operator has higher priority then
>   '/'

Incorrect. Both `*` and `/` have equal [**precedence**](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) and are left-associative.

After evaluating the parenthesis expression we have:

```
(x + y - 1) / y * y = z / y * y      // where z = x + y -1

                    = (z / y) * y    // because of associativity.
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but as far as I recall / and * have same precedence. So the result should be (x+y+1).

Maybe you should say (x+y+1)/(y*y) if that's what you want the result to be.

It never costs much to disambiguate in any case.

As to using ((x+y-1)/y)*y to round up or down as the case may be, this is a dubious and not very portable practice. Several reasons: 1/ you must know or remember that y is some sort of int, 2/ x must also be some sort of int, 3/ results may vary depending on the compiler.

Comment: It is true that different types will result different values, but why it may vary depending on compiler? I think the result is very well defined in a compliant implementation (with the minor exception of floating point rounding errors).

Comment: For one, int is not always the same size (bytes). So you might be wrapping around or overflowing at a different point, depends how big your numbers are. Also not every C compiler is ANSI.

Comment: that's a valid argument. However, for the 2nd comment, I mentioned a **compliant** implementation in my comment.

Comment: @ysap - indeed you did, and you'd probably be right 99.9% of the time ;-)